# iMacros ignores some of the clicks

Tags: imacros

I wrote the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button> Click </button>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('OK');
  })
</script>
</html>
```

As you can see, the purpose of this code is launching a dialog box whenever the user clicks the 'button'.

I just started to use iMacros for Chrome, and it seems that iMacros doesn't "catch" this click.

Do you know why and how it can be resolved?

Comment: It's also not perfect in FF. Is there any way to edit the macro file and add something like: "CLICK X=100 Y=100" (when (100,100) is the coordinates of the position of the mouse when clicked)  ?